# Update KnockoutJS viewModel using mapping and localStorage to maintain persistence

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I need the data saved to localStorage, "savedData", to update the currently empty view model when the page is revisted/refreshed, possibly using the KO mapping plug-in in the line:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(this, retrievedData);
```

But of course it's not working!

```
function viewModel() {

    var self = this;

    self.employees = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.removeEmployee = function (employee) {
        self.employees.remove(employee);
    };

    self.addEmployee = function () {
        self.employees.push(new Employee());
    };

    self.save = function () {
        var savedData = ko.toJSON(this);
        localStorage.setItem('savedData', savedData);
        //console.log('savedData', JSON.parse(savedData))
    }

    if (localStorage && localStorage.getItem('savedData')) {
        var retrievedData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('savedData'));
        ko.mapping.fromJS(this, retrievedData);
    }
}

var vm = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in `fromJS` parameters. Second parameter is mapping options but you are trying to pass data instead. Proper usage should be following

```
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(retrievedData, mappingOptions);
```

If you don't want map `retreivedData` to `viewModel` using `mappingOptions`

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(retrievedData, {}, viewModel);
```

This will convert your data to `viewModel` without any specific mapping options.

---

***NOTE:*** If you call `mapping.fromJS` with two arguments and [second argument IS mapping object (`__ko_mapping__` property defined)](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping/blob/master/knockout.mapping.js#L96) it will treat second argument as a `viewModel` and you can use function in a different manner:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(retrievedData, viewModel);
```

Basically this scenario is valid when you are not ***creating*** `viewModel`, but instead ***updating*** previously created using mapping `viewModel` with some data.

---

***ANSWER:*** You should update your code co map properly by passing empty `options` parameter. An of course data should go first:

```
if (localStorage && localStorage.getItem('savedData')) {
    var retrievedData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('savedData'));
    ko.mapping.fromJS(retrievedData, {}, self);
}
```

Comment: Ahhhh, switch-a-roo! Thanks! I've had to add back to the data bindings $parent to get click functions to work, but other than that all good!